# Code acting differently inside of a function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i've got this set of code here in R that seperates a dataframe containing tweets by their day posted. I'm finding a weird interaction where, if i was to run the code outside of the function, it works perfectly fine. However, running it within the function only outputs a single row into the output frame, whereas there should be many more. This has me stumped as i cannot find anything else about this.

```
function(dataFrame, output){
  dates <- c("2022-04-15","2022-04-16","2022-04-17",
              "2022-04-18","2022-04-19","2022-04-20")
  t <- nrow(dataFrame)
  for(i in 1:t){
    currentchar <- toString(dataFrame$name[i])
    print(currentchar)
    currentFrame <- get(toString(dataFrame$name[i]))
    counts <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
    
    frameLength <- nrow(currentFrame)
    for(j in 1:frameLength){
      time <- currentFrame$created_at[j]
      date <- substr(time, 1, 10)
      print(date)
      print(j)
      num <- switch(date,
                     "2022-04-20" = (counts[6] <- counts[6] + 1),
                     "2022-04-19" = (counts[5] <- counts[5] + 1),
                     "2022-04-18" = (counts[4] <- counts[4] + 1),
                     "2022-04-17" = (counts[3] <- counts[3] + 1),
                     "2022-04-16" = (counts[2] <- counts[2] + 1),
                     "2022-04-15" = (counts[1] <- counts[1] + 1))
    }
    
    for(k in 1:6){
      f <- data.frame(toString(characters_list[i]), dates[k], counts[k])
      colnames(f) <- c('name', 'date', 'count')
      output <<- rbind(f, output)
    }
  }
}
```

When ran outside of the function, the code produces the result i want, but when ran within it produces a single row of the dataframe.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of scoping. Everything inside the function gets deleted when you get out of the function.

Your function doesn't return any value. But the returned value of the function is that what stays after the function call.

```
# assign the function to a name
myfunction <- function(dataFrame, output){
  dates <- c("2022-04-15","2022-04-16","2022-04-17",
              "2022-04-18","2022-04-19","2022-04-20")
  t <- nrow(dataFrame)
  for(i in 1:t){
    currentchar <- toString(dataFrame$name[i])
    print(currentchar)
    currentFrame <- get(toString(dataFrame$name[i]))
    counts <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
    
    frameLength <- nrow(currentFrame)
    for(j in 1:frameLength){
      time <- currentFrame$created_at[j]
      date <- substr(time, 1, 10)
      print(date)
      print(j)
      num <- switch(date,
                     "2022-04-20" = (counts[6] <- counts[6] + 1),
                     "2022-04-19" = (counts[5] <- counts[5] + 1),
                     "2022-04-18" = (counts[4] <- counts[4] + 1),
                     "2022-04-17" = (counts[3] <- counts[3] + 1),
                     "2022-04-16" = (counts[2] <- counts[2] + 1),
                     "2022-04-15" = (counts[1] <- counts[1] + 1))
    }
    
    for(k in 1:6){
      f <- data.frame(toString(characters_list[i]), dates[k], counts[k])
      colnames(f) <- c('name', 'date', 'count')
      output <<- rbind(f, output)
    }
  }
  # return `output` as the result
  output
}

# now, you can call and assign the function's result at the same time:
result <- myfunction(dataFrame, output)

# and `result` is what your `f` should be at the end of the calculation.
```

Comment: This doesnt appear to work either, the dataframe that im storing the output to is instead, completely empty, rather than the output dataframe having a single entry.

Comment: Well, the problem is, one would do this totally differently in R. Not with for loops.

Comment: can you explain in human words, what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: This function is looping through 52 datasets and checking the date on each entry. It will then up the count on whatever date is found. Once all entries have been checked on a single dataset, it will add 6 entries to a new dataset, containing the name of the original dataset, the number of entries it found with that date, and the date itself, before moving on to the next dataset. Overall this should produce 6 entries in the final dataset for each initial dataset, detailing how many of each date was found in each.
My problem is that the code does not work properly within the function.

Comment: you refer suddenly to `characters_list` which is nowhere mentioned/defined before ... I guess it is the $names columns' content?